# 'This field name is not known' error (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is a strange problem I have run into.

My record select formula is as follows, I have dumbed it down for purposes of this error:

```
reportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula = " {@ClientName} = 'Smith' "
```

If I copy this exact selection statement into Crystal it previews fine, but when run from .NET I get

> 'This field name is not known'.

The problem is occurring at the `@ClientName` formula field.

`@ClientName` simply contains:

```
formula = {aw_illust.CL1LNAM}
```

I can also set it to just a blank string (formula = "") and it still gives

> 'This field name is not known.'

Here is the strange part, if I bypass the formula and put the formula text straight into .NET everything works fine.

```
reportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula = " {aw_illust.CL1LNAM} = 'Smith' "
```

That is the same record selection, except with the '`@ClientName`' formula replaced with '`{aw_illust.CL1LNAM}`'. It just happens on this one report, I have many other Crystal Reports working with formulas referenced in .NET just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You say it's working elsewhere – would you post a sample illustrating what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you are not using your {@ClientName} formula anywhere on report; Crystal Reports tends to ignore unused fields, formulas etc. Place {@ClientName} field somewhere in report (header or some similar section) and suppress it - this way you don't mess up report design, but CR should know about that formula afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Which syntax has the formula? If it is crystal syntax then change it to basic syntax. Or change the content of the formula to crystal syntax (without "formula =")

Answer (score 0):

You could create a parameter like `{?ClientName}` and set that from .NET, and then put a select formula in Crystal like `{@ClientName} = {?ClientName}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the report with the selection criteria you'd like then display what the `reportDocument` class sees using something like:

```
TextBox1.text = reportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula
```

This would confirm that your syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me when I copied existing report to be used as the new one, You can first open report in report viewer ,In my case

[image]

but the query that loading report has no selection with name **DateLocal Transaction** so I got this error, the resolve is to either use only those that are require (Extras has nothing to do with the error) or rename selection value in query.